# I do not get the real value in days, hours and minutes by subtracting two dates

Tags: momentjs

I am new in this library. I have 2 dates, and I would like to obtain the difference in days, minutes and hours between both. but for some reason the output is an erroneous data. I have based on this page

[image]

to get the exact difference and it is different to my result. what am I doing wrong?

```
var now=2018-07-04 00:37:02;
var then=2018-07-05 08:00:00;

moment.utc(moment(now,"YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then,"YYYY/MM/DD 
HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");

output is : 16:37
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two significant problems here:

- `a.diff(b)` returns `a - b`, so it will be positive if `a` is later than `b`. You're using `now.diff(then)` effectively, so that will currently give a negative difference, and I suspect you're expecting it to be positive.
- You're turning a *duration in time* into a date/time using `moment.utc`. The value just *isn't* a date/time, so shouldn't be treated as one. Instead, use `moment.duration(...)` to convert to a momentjs `Duration` object, which you can then handle however you want.

Here's a complete example, having broken out each of the conversions involved for readability:

```
var now = "2018-07-04 00:37:02";
var then = "2018-07-05 08:00:00";
var parsedNow = moment(now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
var parsedThen = moment(then, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
var diff = parsedThen.diff(parsedNow);
var durationDiff = moment.duration(diff);
alert(durationDiff.toISOString());
```

Output: PT31H22M58S

That 31 hours is 1 day + 7 hours etc. While a duration has the concept of days, months, years etc, I don't see any way of normalizing a duration created from `diff` to "1 day 7 hours". (It could certainly be done, but only as far as days  - you couldn't normalize to include months without providing more context.)

Comment: Thank you very much, for now it is good for me to use 31 hours in this case. I wish there was a way to show days, hours and minutes using moment